# cannot import smartsheet after installing pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Smartsheet API beginner using python is in need of help

Hi, everyone. I am working on smartsheet API and am trying to follow the website to get some exercise first from https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#sdks-and-sample-code.
I have python 2.7.15 on Mac, so the first step I did was to download the pip folder, and type "pip install smartsheet-python-sdk" on my terminal to install pip. Then I used my .py file to test out the code, I ran the first line `import smartsheet` and there is an error already.

The message I got is below, any suggestions will be appreciated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my name /Desktop/charity.py", line 6, in <module>
    import smartsheet
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smartsheet/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .smartsheet import Smartsheet, fresh_operation, AbstractUserCalcBackoff  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smartsheet/smartsheet.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .models import Error, ErrorResult
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smartsheet/models/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .access_token import AccessToken
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smartsheet/models/access_token.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..types import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smartsheet/types.py", line 26, in <module>
    from enum import Enum
ImportError: No module named enum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enum` module [was added in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) but you're on Python 2.7.  The smartsheet platform claims to support Python 2.7 but it also [requires the import](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/smartsheet/types.py) of `enum` for it to work.

You can submit an issue to the project and hope that they fix it or upgrade to Python 3.4 and beyond.

Comment: Thank you GiraffeMan91, I install the python 3.4.4 and it seems fine now. Appreciate it!!

Comment: No problem, please hit the checkmark under the voting icons on the left if this answers your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per a previous answer, the error is due to using Python 2, while enum was added in Python 3.4. However, there is a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/) if you need to use Python 2 for some reason.

Simply install with  `pip install enum34`. I tested smartsheet with the enum34 library using Python 2.7.16 and was successful.